# ARM/U-Boot: kernel v3.18 does not boot with ramdisk in FIT image

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, u-boot, buildroot, initramfs

I am struggling to get a Broadcom ARM9 platform to boot from a kernel that does not have a built-in initrd image.

I have successfully compiled the [vendor kernel](https://github.com/halmartin/switch-12-32-ms225) and [U-Boot](https://github.com/halmartin/u-boot-ms225) for the platform. Note that both kernel and U-Boot are forks from upstream, so I am unable to test with mainline releases.

I can successfully boot a kernel with a built-in initramfs `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE=rootfs.cpio` generated by [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/):

```sh
u-boot> bootm
## Booting kernel from FIT Image at 70000000 ...
   Using '24' configuration
   Trying 'kernel' kernel subimage
     Description:  Kernel
     Type:         Kernel Image
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x700000bc
     Data Size:    6895136 Bytes = 6.6 MiB
     Architecture: ARM
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: 0x60008000
     Entry Point:  0x60008000
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   ddb314e7d5409237fe4c00644d70c55f9f18c67c
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
## Flattened Device Tree from FIT Image at 70000000
   Using '24' configuration
   Trying 'fdt24' FDT blob subimage
     Description:  MS225-24 DTB
     Type:         Flat Device Tree
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x706937c4
     Data Size:    9148 Bytes = 8.9 KiB
     Architecture: ARM
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   ff70437562340a11455a1b3552e745539d903c33
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
   Loading FDT from 0x706937c4 to 0x00000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x(null)
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK
boot_prep_linux commandline: console=ttyS0,115200n8 earlyprintk ubi.mtd=ubi
   Loading Device Tree to 9fee1000, end 9fee63bb ... OK

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.18.131 (root@40e39c311f61) (gcc version 11.3.0 (Buildroot 2023.02.1) ) #1 Thu May 18 20:23:29 UTC 2023
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [414fc091] revision 1 (ARMv7), cr=10c53c7d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine model: Meraki Brumby
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
```

This is the same method the vendor firmware uses to boot.

Contents of the image tree source file:

```dts
/dts-v1/;

/ {
        description = "Meraki Brumby FIT Image";
        #address-cells = <1>;

        images {
                kernel {
                        description = "Kernel";
                        data = /incbin/("zImage");
                        type = "kernel";
                        arch = "arm";
                        os = "linux";
                        compression = "none";
                        load = <0x60008000>;
                        entry = <0x60008000>;
                        hash {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
                fdt24 {
                        description = "MS225-24 DTB";
                        data = /incbin/("meraki-brumby24p.dtb");
                        type = "flat_dt";
                        arch = "arm";
                        compression = "none";
                        load = <0x0>;
                        hash {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
                fdt48 {
                        description = "MS225-48 DTB";
                        data = /incbin/("meraki-brumby48.dtb");
                        type = "flat_dt";
                        arch = "arm";
                        compression = "none";
                        load = <0x0>;
                        hash {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
        };

        configurations {
                default = "24";
                24 {
                        description = "Meraki brumby 24";
                        kernel = "kernel";
                        fdt = "fdt24";
                        hash {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
                48 {
                        description = "Meraki brumby 48";
                        kernel = "kernel";
                        fdt = "fdt48";
                        hash {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
        };

};
```

**However** if I take the same kernel, and build it without `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE` but instead provide (the same) `rootfs.cpio` in the FIT image, it does not boot:

```sh
u-boot> bootm
## Booting kernel from FIT Image at 70000000 ...
   Using '24' configuration
   Trying 'kernel' kernel subimage
     Description:  Kernel
     Type:         Kernel Image
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x700000bc
     Data Size:    1879088 Bytes = 1.8 MiB
     Architecture: ARM
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: 0x60008000
     Entry Point:  0x60008000
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   8ba797a97ddd6b5925172644307af1e12dd1bc6c
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
## Loading init Ramdisk from FIT Image at 70000000 ...
   Using '24' configuration
   Trying 'ramdisk' ramdisk subimage
     Description:  ramdisk
     Type:         RAMDisk Image
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x701cadcc
     Data Size:    4946988 Bytes = 4.7 MiB
     Architecture: ARM
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: 0x00000000
     Entry Point:  0x00000000
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   69d44c28fccf9babbe018511ef3e4fe9c043c427
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
## Flattened Device Tree from FIT Image at 70000000
   Using '24' configuration
   Trying 'fdt24' FDT blob subimage
     Description:  MS225-24 DTB
     Type:         Flat Device Tree
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x70682ae0
     Data Size:    9148 Bytes = 8.9 KiB
     Architecture: ARM
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   ff70437562340a11455a1b3552e745539d903c33
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x70682ae0
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK
boot_prep_linux commandline: console=ttyS0,115200n8 earlyprintk ubi.mtd=ubi
   Loading Ramdisk to 9fa2f000, end 9fee6c2c ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 9fa29000, end 9fa2e3bb ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

Contents of the image tree source file:

```dts
/dts-v1/;

/ {
        description = "Meraki Brumby FIT Image";
        #address-cells = <1>;

        images {
                kernel {
                        description = "Kernel";
                        data = /incbin/("zImage");
                        type = "kernel";
                        arch = "arm";
                        os = "linux";
                        compression = "none";
                        load = <0x60008000>;
                        entry = <0x60008000>;
                        hash {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
                ramdisk {
                        description = "ramdisk";
                        data = /incbin/("rootfs.cpio.lzma");
                        type = "ramdisk";
                        arch = "arm";
                        os = "linux";
                        compression = "none";
                        load = <0x0>;
                        entry = <0x0>;
                        hash {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
                fdt24 {
                        description = "MS225-24 DTB";
                        data = /incbin/("meraki-brumby24p.dtb");
                        type = "flat_dt";
                        arch = "arm";
                        compression = "none";
                        hash {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
                fdt48 {
                        description = "MS225-48 DTB";
                        data = /incbin/("meraki-brumby48.dtb");
                        type = "flat_dt";
                        arch = "arm";
                        compression = "none";
                        hash {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
        };

        configurations {
                default = "24";
                24 {
                        description = "Meraki brumby 24";
                        kernel = "kernel";
                        ramdisk = "ramdisk";
                        fdt = "fdt24";
                        hash {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
                48 {
                        description = "Meraki brumby 48";
                        kernel = "kernel";
                        ramdisk = "ramdisk";
                        fdt = "fdt48";
                        hash {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
        };

};
```

According to [this mailing list post](https://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2009-November/063821.html) the `load` address of the `ramdisk` does not matter for a FIT image, although it is required by U-Boot. Failing to provide the `load` address of the `ramdisk` results in the following error:

```auto
Can't get ramdisk subimage load address!
Ramdisk image is corrupt or invalid
```

The kernel is compiled with `CONFIG_RD_LZMA=y`, and providing `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE=rootfs.cpio.lzma` works, so it is not an issue of the kernel being unable to decompress the ramdisk specified in the FIT image.

The kernel with built-in initrd is around ~70KB larger than the FIT image (6895136 bytes versus 6826076), which I haven't investigated but assume may be due to overhead of including a built-in initrd. Both the kernel and initrd are LZMA compressed. I have tried other compression methods (`gzip`) without success.

I am also fairly confident this is not an issue of memory mapping or overwriting, as I have mistakenly created a FIT image containing a zImage with built-in initrd, `ramdisk` from the FIT image, and device tree (totaling ~14MB). If there was an issue with the `load` or `entry` being incorrect, I would expect the FIT-with-ramdisk scenario to fail too, and it does not:

```sh
u-boot> bootm
## Booting kernel from FIT Image at 70000000 ...
   Using '24' configuration
   Trying 'kernel' kernel subimage
     Description:  Kernel
     Type:         Kernel Image
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x700000bc
     Data Size:    8495752 Bytes = 8.1 MiB
     Architecture: ARM
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: 0x60008000
     Entry Point:  0x60008000
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   ec94a62986d70635ccd7b023d600b83c22e3aff0
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
## Loading init Ramdisk from FIT Image at 70000000 ...
   Using '24' configuration
   Trying 'ramdisk' ramdisk subimage
     Description:  ramdisk
     Type:         RAMDisk Image
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x7081a424
     Data Size:    5345280 Bytes = 5.1 MiB
     Architecture: ARM
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: 0x61008000
     Entry Point:  0x61008000
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   1dc96437bf2424fc372851148cbf0296c5b61354
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
## Flattened Device Tree from FIT Image at 70000000
   Using '24' configuration
   Trying 'fdt24' FDT blob subimage
     Description:  MS225-24 DTB
     Type:         Flat Device Tree
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x70d3350c
     Data Size:    9010 Bytes = 8.8 KiB
     Architecture: ARM
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   58a2bd3c7bfe085020e704b6655861e0e4a274d1
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
   Loading FDT from 0x70d3350c to 0x00000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x(null)
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK
boot_prep_linux commandline: console=ttyS0,115200n8 earlyprintk ubi.mtd=ubi mtdparts=m25p80:0xc0000(u-boot)ro,0x10000(env),0x30000(shmoo)ro,0xA00000(fit),0x500000(overlay)
   Loading Ramdisk to 9f9cd000, end 9fee6000 ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 9f9c7000, end 9f9cc331 ... OK

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.18.131 (root@0b1f5507523e) (gcc version 8.4.0 (Buildroot 2021.02.7) ) #1 Mon May 1 20:05:46 UTC 2023
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [414fc091] revision 1 (ARMv7), cr=10c53c7d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine model: Meraki Brumby
```

The bare kernel, without a built-in initrd, and without a `ramdisk` in the FIT image, also fails to boot:

```sh
u-boot> bootm
## Booting kernel from FIT Image at 70000000 ...
   Using '24' configuration
   Trying 'kernel' kernel subimage
     Description:  Kernel
     Type:         Kernel Image
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x700000bc
     Data Size:    1879952 Bytes = 1.8 MiB
     Architecture: ARM
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: 0x60008000
     Entry Point:  0x60008000
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   2fb4e06ea0400d54fa14cc8427ab60036c06b9c5
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
## Flattened Device Tree from FIT Image at 70000000
   Using '24' configuration
   Trying 'fdt24' FDT blob subimage
     Description:  MS225-24 DTB
     Type:         Flat Device Tree
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x701cb134
     Data Size:    9148 Bytes = 8.9 KiB
     Architecture: ARM
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   ff70437562340a11455a1b3552e745539d903c33
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
   Loading FDT from 0x701cb134 to 0x00000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x(null)
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK
boot_prep_linux commandline: console=ttyS0,115200n8 earlyprintk ubi.mtd=ubi
   Loading Device Tree to 9fee1000, end 9fee63bb ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

Kernel [.config](https://gist.github.com/halmartin/1fbb3c4163c87b97821799a5857480a5) (without `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE` but otherwise identical to the "it boots!" scenario).

Why won't this kernel boot without a built-in initrd?! (╯ರ ~ ರ）╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: You are not using an initrd or have a ramdisk image. You are trying to use an initramfs, which is populated with a cpio archive. Just because booting with initramfs reuses the older initrd methods doesn't mean you also can be sloppy with terminology. If I was in your shoes, I would temporarily bypass the FIT, and test booting with the old fashion, discrete images method:  `bootz <zImage addr> <cpio archive addr>:<archive length> <dtb addr>`. You could also try U-Boot commands to extract these images from the FIT.

Comment: I think it want FDT before any attached filesystem.  AFAIR, I had this issue and went with what the vendor did.  Ie, it was impossible/difficult to have  a detached FS and FDT.  You will have to enable early_boot printk and pass debug options.  Why don't you want a built-in image?  It can just `chroot` or pivot.